# Start a program in active user session with PowerShell remoting

Tags: .net, powershell, remoting

Is it possible to detect that a specific user has an open session on a computer and to open a process in that session so that the application can be interacted with by the user using PowerShell remoting?

How would I go around detecting which users have sessions open on the machine and what their state is (active, idle, disconnected, etc...)?  How would I launch an application within one of those sessions?

**UPDATE**
I have found that you can identify the session ID a process is running in:

```
PS > ( Get-Process notepad ).SessionId
1
```

I can't seem to find anyway to specify the session ID for a process when you start it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Powershell cannot do this, but microsoft's (previously sysinternal's) tool PSEXEC can do this. Take a look at the -i parameter:

```
 -i         Run the program so that it interacts with the desktop of the
            specified session on the remote system. If no session is
            specified the process runs in the console session.
```